# Problems with LOCAL INFILE after switching to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, file-io

Anyone that is aware of the issues with using LOCAL INFILE in PHP will understand my frustration with this.

I previously got LOCAL INFILE working properly in all my PHP scripts by using the 128 flag in my connection call.

```
mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,false,128)
```

I am now trying to switch to mysqli since the old mysql is depreciated.
I have tried everything I could find on every forum out there with no luck.

My connection call in mysqli seems fine:

```
$connection = mysqli_init();
if (!$connection) {die('mysqli_init failed');}
if (!mysqli_options($connection, MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0')) {die('Setting MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND failed');}
if (!mysqli_options($connection, MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5)) {die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT failed');}
if (!mysqli_options($connection, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE,true)) {die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE failed');}

if (!mysqli_real_connect($connection, DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_SELECT)) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

My my.cnf file contains the appropriate parameters:

```
[mysql]
local-infile=1

[mysqld]
local-infile=1
```

my php.ini also contains the appropriate parameters:

```
[MySQLi]
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
```

The query even returns true when executed! But i still get no data loaded in my table.

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$file}' INTO TABLE {$table} FIELDS TERMINATED BY '{$fieldTerm}' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '{$lineTerm}' IGNORE {$skipLines} LINES";
if(mysqli_query($connection,$query)) {$message .= "Load Complete <br />";} //Message returns with "Load Complete".
```

Other than doing a system() call, I have no idea what to do to make this work. It worked fine with mysql, just not now with mysqli.

Why is LOCAL INFILE so difficult? This has been an ongoing problem for way too long.

EDIT:

Strange, when I run mysqli_info() after the query, it says it executed properly.

```
Records: 4 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 0
```

There are 4 records in the test file, so this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search brought up the following PHP Bug entry: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55737.

This issue seems to revolve around the php.ini setting open_basedir: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

> The LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE function does not work with mysql5.5 and php5.4.4 on Debian Wheezy with open_basedir restrictions in place.
>   It works perfectly fine when open_basedir is disabled or set to nothing.

EDIT (solution for reference): OP's issue was with the "SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0" init command. It was loading and processing, but not being committed to the db.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Ive seen that post as well. Im on PHP5.5.11 and open_basedir is off anyway. Thanks though!

Comment: Now I'm just taking stabs in the dark to see what sticks: Does ini_get('values') give you the expected results? Can you remove the keyword LOCAL from the query, and set the filename to an absolute path to the file?

Comment: Very good suggestions. Unfortunately ini_get returns true for both the mysql and mysqli.allow_local_infile parameters. I removed LOCAL and attempted to use an absolute file path and it yielded the same results ive been getting. The data does not load. Its just odd that mysqli_info would return an appropriate affected record count when there was no actual change in the database.

Comment: Dumb question: Do you ever commit the query?

Comment: Commit the query? Isnt it committed durring the "if(mysqli_query($connection,$query))"? Am i missing a step completely here?

Comment: It's executed, not necessarily committed. Try removing the MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND line and see if it works.   That's the only other thing I can think of. It's picking up the file, processing it, but it's not ending up in your DB, and I see "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0"

Comment: Ohh my god... I am incredibly sorry for wasting your time. That was exactly it. I pulled that SET AUTOCOMMIT=0 from a "getting started in mysqli" guide and really didnt think that one through. I truly appreciate your help, and again, my apologies for this waste of time of a problem.

Comment: Not a waste of time--someone else will inevitably have a similar problem (especially if they work from the same getting started guide you did). Thanks for the contribution!