# mysqli_info and mysqli_num_rows not working

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli, load-data-infile

I have written PHP which will successfully connect to MySQL database and upload CSV to MySQL.

I am trying to get the results of the query using mysqli_info(), but I get no result from this function.

I also tried mysqli_num_rows() but this also returns blank. Everything else works correctly without any errors. When I attempt to run mysqli_info(), there is simply no result, nor any error.

```
$mysqli_link = mysqli_connect($mysqli_hostname, $mysqli_user, 
                              $mysqli_password, $mysqli_database);

$workingfile = "/arb/path/to/file";
$tablename = "`table_name`";

$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".$workingfile."' INTO TABLE ".$tablename.
         " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n';";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_link, $query);

//deletes temporary file from server
unlink($workingfile); 
echo "CSV uploaded successfully to database.<br /><br />"; 

$info = mysqli_info($mysqli_link); // returns empty 
//$info = "".mysqli_num_rows($result); // does not work either, returns empty
echo "Result: ".$info; 
mysqli_close($mysqli_link);
```

This is my first post, so please let me know if I post anything incorrectly or needs editing.

Thank you,

RamzGT

Comment: How does it not work?  What error do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot this? Have you verified the query is correct? Have it you run it from the command line?

Comment: Since I assume this is all your code, you arent creating a connection to the database. You gotta do that first.

Comment: error might be silenced, try adding `or die mysqli_error($mysqli_link)` to every mysqli function call.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430161/problems-with-local-infile-after-switching-to-mysqli and see if that is relevant to your issue.

Comment: @JohnConde - I am not getting any errors, nor any result from $info = mysqli_info($mysqli_link);

Comment: @user3678068 - I added "or die..." but no errors are being returned on mysqli statements.

Comment: @Len_D Thank you, I have already reviewed that document prior but was not helpful.

Comment: are there other queries happening between the query and the `mysqli_info()`? even a select? that select would then be the last query on the link, and mysqli_info() doesn't return any info with select http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.info.php

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - No, there are no other queries being run between. Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an auto increment column and you try to populate it's value with a value from your CSV file, probably that value is already in use into your table and that's way the operation could not be completed. So, you should remove the value for the auto incremental column from your CSV file and try again.

Comment: Just so everyone knows for posterity, I do not think these comments apply to newer versions of PHP. Best of luck!